# Why does System.Out.println[array[1]); while using String.split make array out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, input, text

Here is A snip of some basic code to a project i am working on:

```
System.out.println("ENter a paragraph:")
String input = sc.next();
String[] ArrayIn = new String[100];
ArrayIn = input.split("\\.");
```

And then I do the basic for loop, using ArrayIn[i].

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayIn.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ArrayIn[i]);
}
```

But anything over a sentence, such as *I like meat. I like beef* would print out *I like meat* and then would give me an error. I'm only a beginner, so I don't know all the meaty parts of java. May you please give me a simple explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Please, post the "basic for loop"

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < ArrayIn.length; i++){    then System.out.println(ArrayIn[i]);

Comment: @NicholasBegg In your title you mention `array[1]` but when printing in a for loop like that why not use `array[i]`? Otherwise you're always printing the second element.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53781950/edit) your question, don't use comments for this.

Comment: Anyway, unless you actually wanted this: `String[] ArrayIn = new String[100];` it's asking for trouble. Just do `String[] ArrayIn = input.split("\\.");`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you're getting. It works fine for me

Comment: Can you show your exact code?

Comment: @NicholasBegg actually that's what *we* are asking from *you* :)

Comment: the stack trace from the error should indicate exactly which line number the exception is being generated - we need the code of that line (better a [mcve])

Comment: Ok. My copy and paste feature is gone. I tried everything.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `for loop`, use this

```
// split phrases by '.'
String[] sentences= input.split("\\.");
for(int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sentences[i]);
}
```

your problem was that you are using `sc.next()`. That means that when your input is `hello world. bye`, it will take it as 3 different inputs separated by spaces `['hello', 'world.', 'bye']`. You should use `sc.nextLine()` instead. Then the full code will be

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ENter a paragraph:");
String input = sc.nextLine();
String[] sentences = input.split("\\.");
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sentences[i]);
}
```

Comment: I will try to do that. Right now, my computer is not working properly.

Comment: @NicholasBegg can you share the error? your code works good for me with no errors.

Comment: line 26 java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: so its basically prints food taste good, then java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: Could You please share your code with me so I can compare?

Comment: This looks great!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your code, is this line:

```
String input = sc.next();
```

that should be changed to:

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
```

beacause you want to get the full line splitted.  
These lines:

```
String[] ArrayIn = new String[100];
ArrayIn = input.split("\\.");
```

do not produce any error, but could be merged to:

```
String[] ArrayIn = input.split("\\.");
```

so I can't see why you got any errors from the code you posted. 
Maybe this is not the whole code.

Comment: Thanks, is it because it only reads the next word using next()?

Comment: Yes, this is what next() does.

Comment: Thanks. I should've known! I never could figure out a difference until now.

Answer (score 0):

next() can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by a space. Also, next() places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

nextLine() reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, nextLine() positions the cursor in the next line.

That's why use:
sc.nextLine()